# How to resolve Babel issue when trying to run Geolocation on Android device?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, babeljs

I am trying to add [Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation) to my ionic app, running these commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install @ionic-native/geolocation
```

And then trying to run it on my android device (`ionic cordova run android`).

However, I'm getting this error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL]
>   C:\Users\damie\Documents\Ionic\geoLocation\www\0-es2015.js: Could not
>   find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in
>   ./available-plugins.js for it.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this:

1. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. Add “resolutions”: `{ “@babel/preset-env”: “^7.8.7” }` to *package.json*

[image]

3. Run `npm install npm-force-resolutions --save-dev`
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npx npm-force-resolutions`
6. Run `npm install again`

Then run your app (i.e. `ionic cordova run android`), & should work